# How do I, or can I, handle empty asp.Net Friendly URLs with empty parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing

I've just started playing with Microsoft's ASP.Net FriendlyURLs and have come to a point where I'm stuck. I tried Googleing for the answer, but didn't find anything that answered my question...

We have a page we want to route, OrderHistory.aspx.

This page is paged so we need to be able to specify which page we want, and as well as that, it can have a search parameter sent to it to search the results.

logically, this means we want 2 (or more routes)

```
        routes.MapPageRoute("", "OrderList/{page}","~/OrderHistory.aspx");
        routes.MapPageRoute("", "OrderList/{search}", "~/OrderHistory.aspx");
        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "", 
            "OrderList/{page}/{search}", 
            "~/OrderHistory.aspx", 
            true, 
            new RouteValueDictionary { {"page", "1"}, {"search", "Adobe"} }
            );
```

My problem is that if I search for either a page OR a search, how does my code know which parameter I want to use? 
To get around this I tried to specify a page that has both parameters with a default set, but this doesnt seem to work.

If I enter http://localhost/orderlist//dell into my browser, it ignore the "//" (in my mind, an empty parameter value) and just has dell in the first parameter, and the default (Adobe) in the second)...

How do I get it so I can enter one or more (or none) and get the page to redirect correctly?

Thanks

Comment: You must distinguish your URLs *somehow*.  e.g. `OrderList/page/{page}` and `OrderList/search/{search}`.  Empty URL segments are not valid.  You cannot have a URL with such an empty segment, per [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.3)

Comment: Well that answers that... Thanks Amy